# php mysql update array from table loop rows

Tags: php, mysql

how to update multiple rows with one time submittion? when i update one row, the other row becomes updated with the same value. how do i update each rows separately with one submit?

here is my php:

```
$receipt = "SELECT * FROM receipt_tbl WHERE receipt_no = '$no' "; 
$receipt_fetch = mysqli_query($con,$receipt) or die("we");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($receipt_fetch);
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){    
    for($num=0;$num<$count ; $num++) {
            $item =$_POST['item'][$num];
            $quantity = $_POST['quantity'][$num];
            $price = $_POST['price'][$num];
            $discount = $_POST['discount'][$num];
            $query2 = "UPDATE `receipt_tbl` SET `receipt_no`='$rcpt',`item`='$item',`quantity`='$quantity',`price`='$price',`discount`='$discount' WHERE receipt_no = '$no'"; 
            $update2 = mysqli_query($con,$query2) or die("we2");     
    }
}
```

html form:

```
<?php
while($receipt_row = mysqli_fetch_array($receipt_fetch)){
    echo"
<tr>
    <td>
    <input type='text'  name='item[]'value='$receipt_row[item]' required> 
    </td>
    <td class='text-right'>
    <input type='number'name='quantity[]' value='$receipt_row[quantity]' required>
    </td>
    <td class='text-right'>
    <input type='number'name='price[]' value='$receipt_row[price]'required>
    </td>
    <td class='text-right'>
    <input type='text' name='discount[]' value='$receipt_row[discount]'>
    </td>
</tr>";}
?>
 <input type="submit" value="Update Receipt" name="submit">
```

Comment: where is the form? Incidentally - the sql is totally vulnerable to sql injection - use prepared statements instead.

Comment: in the second code. it will fetch all the data and display in table rows and that's where you can also update the data. i just remove mysql_real_escape_string so it becomes shorter.

Comment: Can u give me a more detailed example

Comment: There is no form in the second piece of code, only a few form elements inside a loop. Is there 1 form around the entire table?

Comment: I mean 1 row in table A update value in col X, Y , and then all other rows will update in col X, Y with the same value?

Comment: yes, it updates all the rows with the same value

Comment: I think that each row in the table should have a hidden field that contains the record id which you can use in the update statement

Comment: The php code has POST fields such as `rcpt`,`fn`,`ln` etc ~ where are these in the form??

Comment: i edited the code, removed some part.

Comment: only 1 form for display and update

Comment: where is the variable `$rcpt` defined?

Comment: Does the select serve any useful purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the following will give an idea how to achieve your desired goal. Copy this as a new demo script and run it to see what the end result is. The commented out code is how you should probably do the real update but as is mentioned below and in comments above it is unclear where $rcpt is defined in your original code sample...

By including a hidden field on each table row you can index that particular ID in the POST data array and use that to update that specific record with values from that particular table row ( or form elements within that table row )

The demo emulates a form that has been filled out ( random data in this case ) - and when submitted will display the effective end queries that will be run. From that you should judge if the output looks like you expect and then implement the `prepared statement` methodology for your actual code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Multi field post update demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
                if( isset( $_POST['submit'], $_POST['id'], $_POST['item'], $_POST['quantity'], $_POST['discount'], $_POST['price'] ) && is_array( $_POST['id'] ) ){
                    /*

                    In practice you will use a prepared statement like this ~
                    though it is unclear where $rcpt is defined


                    $sql='update `receipt_tbl` set `receipt_no`=?, `item`=?, `quantity`=?, `price`=?, `discount`=? where `receipt_no`=?';
                    $stmt=$con->prepare( $sql );

                    if( $stmt ){
                        $stmt->bind_param( 'isiiii', $rcpt, $item, $qty, $price, $discount, $id );

                        foreach( $_POST['id']  as $index => $arr ){
                            $id=$_POST['id'][ $index ];
                            $item=$_POST['item'][ $index ];
                            $qty=$_POST['quantity'][ $index ];
                            $price=$_POST['price'][ $index ];
                            $discount=$_POST['discount'][ $index ];

                            $stmt->execute();
                        }
                        $stmt->free_result();
                        $stmt->close();
                        $con->close();
                    }


                    */

                    /* for demonstration only */
                    $sql='update `receipt_tbl` set `receipt_no`=:rcpt, `item`=:item, `quantity`=:qty, `price`=:price, `discount`=:discount where `receipt_no`=:id;';
                    $rcpt=404;

                    echo '<h1>example sql will effectively be</h1>';
                    foreach( $_POST['id']  as $index => $arr ){
                        $id=$_POST['id'][ $index ];
                        $item=$_POST['item'][ $index ];
                        $qty=$_POST['quantity'][ $index ];
                        $price=$_POST['price'][ $index ];
                        $discount=$_POST['discount'][ $index ];
                        echo str_replace( array(':rcpt',':item',':qty',':price',':discount',':id'), array($rcpt,$item,$qty,$price,$discount,$id), $sql ) . '<br />';
                    }
                }
            } else {
        ?>

        <!-- demo form -->
        <form method='post'>
            <table>
            <?php
                for( $i=0; $i < 10; $i++ ){
                    echo"
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type='text' name='item[]'value='item_$i' required /> 
                            </td>
                            <td class='text-right'>
                                <input type='number' name='quantity[]' value='".rand(1,100)."' required />
                            </td>
                            <td class='text-right'>
                                <input type='number' name='price[]' value='".rand(1,100)."' required />
                            </td>
                            <td class='text-right'>
                                <input type='text' name='discount[]' value='".rand(5,15)."' />
                                <input type='hidden' name='id[]' value='$i' /><!-- This should be the ID for this database record ~ presumably "receipt_no" -->
                            </td>
                        </tr>";
                }
            ?>
            </table>
            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Update All Records' />
        </form>
        <?php

            }//close if/else

        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```